# Convert JSON object to sub object

Tags: php, json

I have following JSON object

```
[{ "item":"foo", "category_id":1 },{ "item":"bar", "category_id": 2},{ "item":"bar", "category_id":3}]
```

needs to convert as follows:

```
[{ "item":"foo", "category_id":1 },{ "item":"bar", "related": { "category_id": [2, 3] }}]
```

I am writing a php function as

```
$previous = [];
$category = [];
$result = [];


foreach ($jsonData as $element) {

    if (in_array($element['item'], $previous)) {
        $category[] = $element['category_id'];
        $result[] = $category;
    } else {
        $previous[] = $element['item'];
        $result[] = $element;
    }
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

which gives output as

```
[{"item":"foo","category_id":1},{"item":"bar","category_id":2},[3]]
```

but i am not able to get the JSON as sub object.
How can i solve it?

Comment: Your first JSON object is incorrect. You have a `"category_id": }` (field name but no value).

Comment: it is now updated with proper value.

Answer (score 0):

If your first item of the array in your object is gonna be the *parent* node you could access to the first item copy it to the new object and then iterate through the next items extracting the ids and then add them to the "category_id": array